# InvalidRegistration in Firebase using POST request

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented a way to send Firebase Push Notifications in NodeJS.
But I need to implement this in Rust instead by using the API.

This is a request I tried to do in Insomia:

```
{
  "data":{
    "title":"New Text Message",
    "image":"https://firebase.google.com/images/social.png",
    "message":"Hello how are you?"
  },
  "to":"iZFSbueRsSJZnjdahRDvZx"
}

Headers:
Content-Type: application/js
Authorization: key=MY_SERVER_KEY
```

This is the response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 2360015634720863373,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the reason this fails is because my `"to"` is invalid. But where can I find the correct value for `"to"` in my POST-request?

In NodeJS executing `console.log(subscription)` gives the following output:

```
{
  endpoint: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eYZWiC4R_Ug:AP99A1bHgyU7jVOf7LEkcVQABVxbPKtFfSvl6jdzo4Xk1gp47xO2S9NaY8EtUvVAb3i2Ru09_iEAZjNpq-R_mY-PmT4Ys9VZ4_m2R49POHvSh6NUiKTe9ixkJYApkk4FpomS1cP8jxEf7',
  expirationTime: null,
  keys: {
    p256dh: 'BGsA9E_T_T_OqHndd7kR55fl-ul2mrhFQiOw9Wr5reGOJOfOXM1_X83X65pGBz01WY3QxGn9TC9zLGuKtH3-Rjk',
    auth: 'iZFSbueRsSJZnjdahRDvZx'
  }
}
```

NodeJS can send push notifications using only this. Where do I get the correct `"to"` value from?

Answer (score 0):

> where can I find the correct value for "to" in my POST-request?

It looks like you're trying to send a message to a specific token, so have a look at the documentation on [getting the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token) on a device, and possible also on [managing tokens on your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens).

Comment: Seems like I need to add the Firebase library. Can it be used in vanilla Javascript client-side?

Comment: To send messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging (as you do with `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/`), you need to get a Firebase Cloud Messaging token which requires the SDK for that product.

Comment: Firebase is horrible.